# Adding Between 0 and 3 Databases to a UserControl

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to add a property called NumDBsToDisplay that gives the option of selecting between 0 and 3 databases to be displayed on my custom control. I can't get the property to show up in the designer, am I missing something here?

Here's the code:

```
Public Property NumDBsToDisplay(ByVal i As Integer) As Integer
Get
  Dim count As Integer = 0
  If cboPridb.Visible = True Then
    count += 1
  End If
  If cboSecdb.Visible = True Then
    count += 1
  End If
  If cboTridb.Visible = True Then
    count += 1
  End If
  Return count
End Get
Set(ByVal value As Integer)
  If value = 0 Then
    cboPridb.Visible = False
    cboSecdb.Visible = False
    cboTridb.Visible = False
  ElseIf value = 1 Then
    lblPridB.Text = "Primary Database"
    cboPridb.Visible = True
    cboSecdb.Visible = False
    cboTridb.Visible = False
  ElseIf value = 2 Then
    lblPridB.Text = "Primary Database"
    lblSecDB.Text = "Secondary Database"
    cboPridb.Visible = True
    cboSecdb.Visible = True
    cboTridb.Visible = False
  Else
    lblPridB.Text = "Primary Database"
    lblSecDB.Width = 131
    lblSecDB.Text = "Secondary Database"
    lblTriDB.Text = "Tertiary Database"
    cboPridb.Visible = True
    cboSecdb.Visible = True
    cboTridb.Visible = True
  End If
End Set
```

End Property

Thank you for the help.

Comment: all those controls wont be available when the properties are initially set by the designer code. also is this a UserControl, sub class of something or from scratch control?

Comment: So can I go into the designer code and make sure my property is initially set after the controls are available, or is there an issue with the way I am designing this property in general?

Comment: The designer doesn't understand what that `i As Integer` parameter is all about, so it ignores the "property", since it *acts* more like a function and a method.  You would have to remove the parameter.

Comment: Designer code is for the designer to mess with, not you.  Lars is right about the param (`value` *is* the param) but you might still have a problem referencing a control before it has been created.  That code might be better off in the load event

Comment: As soon as I removed the i As Integer parameter it started working as intended, thanks both of you

Comment: ...and that Visible property is special (or weird if you prefer).  You can set it to true, but if the control is not on the screen, it's false.  You can't rely on that property the way you are using it.

Comment: I do have one more issue though; my SetNumDBsToDisplay is taking any integer as input. Is there a way for me to restrict the parameter value to {0,1,2,3} only?

Comment: Not really, other than an enum to make it convenient.  If the number isn't within your range, you should throw an exception.

Comment: Thank you, I am new to vb.net so I am trying to get the hang of it